# How to get iOS device ID in MobileFirst server adapter?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

i want to be able to get the device id of iOS device in MobileFIrst or work light adapter.

I only see this method: WL.Server.getClientDeviceContext()
But this does not contain device id.

The WL.Device.getId() - this is only available in the client.

Please advice- how to get device id of current request in adapter code(javascript)

Edit:
Just to clarify, i am interested in client identifier for the current request made by a client device.

Comment: This needs a better explanation. Are you attempting to get the udid of the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned why you need to capture deviceID at the server.I can think of three ways to achieve it:

a) Use [WL.Server.getClientRequest()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23getClientRequest) API -

```
var req=WL.Server.getClientRequest();                             
WL.Logger.warn("X-WL-DEVICE-ID:::"+ req.getHeader("x-wl-device-id"));
```

b) Use [WL.Server.getCurrentDeviceIdentity()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html%23getCurrentDeviceIdentity) API -

If there is a device identity associated with the device , the method returns the device identity. Device identity object contains deviceID.
  This API was introduced in MF 6.3

c) For older versions , you could try -

```
WL.Server.getActiveUser("wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm");
```

Comment: I will try this out, exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

PS- I have a backend service that needs to log devicecode. So instead of making the front end submit device code, i can capture at server while making the backend call in adapter.

Comment: Note that:
a) only devices generate deviceid. In case of request coming from desktopbrowser/mobileweb app , deviceid will be null.
b) Deviceids can change - OS reset/upgrade etc. Backend logic that prevents access based on deviceid , has to be carefully crafted.
c) If you depend on deviceid count to track number of devices logging into your system, account for point b -deviceids may change.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge...

DeviceId is a client "thing". How do you expect to get from an adapter?
You need to get it in the client and send it to your adapter and then perform any action you may need.

Perhaps it would be easier to help if you will explain your endgoal.

Comment: Adapter is a server resource, it should have some sort of identifier for client that is making the request. I was hoping if that is embedded in the request coming from client.